# Google Cloud Messaging: How to get Registration Ids for device groups?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a downstream message to a device group, but it requires the registration_ids. I am able to get the registration tokens that are used for a regular GCM downstream send( `https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send`) , but I'm assuming the token and id are different things.

For example I'm looking for the registration ids here:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

When I send a regular downstream send message I always get a response of 0 for the canonical_id. Anyone know how I can obtain these ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token and the id are practically the same. If you are using registration_ids then the InstanceID tokens should work in that field to identify the devices.

However consider using [GCM Topic Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/topic-messaging), since you can send to many devices with a single request and not have to compile a list of tokens.